# Heroku CLI: How to reference an app by custom domain? (Example in documentation not working)

Tags: heroku

Heroku's documentation on CLI says to do this ([link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#app_commands)):

> If you have multiple heroku remotes or want to execute an app command outside of a local working copy, you can specify an explicit app name, domain, or git remote as follows:

```
$ heroku info --app myapp
$ heroku info --app www.example.com
$ heroku info --remote staging
```

However, I'm unable to get that second one to work. This is what I get:

```
$ heroku info --app foo
=== foo
[...]

$ heroku domains --app foo
Domain names for foo.herokuapp.com:
foo.example.com

$ heroku info --app foo.example.com
 !    Resource not found
```

At the very least, the documentation seems incorrect. But is it possible to reference an app by one of its custom domains another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, I concur that - using the latest Heroku CLI all the methods work except using the domain name. Is there a particular reason why you want to use that way if the other ways work for you?

Comment: Yes, I'd love to automate steps like pushing to dev.example.com, regardless of what app dev.example.com currently points to.

Comment: pushes can only be done with git remotes. The `--app` attribute is only for using via the Heroku CLI.

Comment: Great point! I could use `heroku info` though to grab the remote URL. Do you know of any easier/cleaner way? (That's a separate question, I realize.)

Comment: I'd just say use a consistent remote name and use that instead. I don't use a remote named Heroku, instead I always use `production` and `staging`. Then the same thing applies, it wouldn't matter which app either was pointing at surely? I opened an issue on the Heroku CLI asking the question about using the domain name though (https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/309)

Comment: That's indeed what I'm doing now. I just wanted to experiment with a different technique of toggling apps via custom domain. It's a different workflow: instead of "pushing" to production, you always only push to staging, and after testing, "flip the switch". Not a huge deal; I just wanted to try it out and see how well such a flow could work on Heroku.